# Is there any way or a specified parameter to use enumerate in python while skipping None values?

Tags: python

Is there any way to enumerate over a list in python while skipping the None values?
I have a requirement where I want to get indices of all list elements which meet a certain arithmetic condition. But my list also contains None values. So whenever a `None` is encountered while enumerating, I get this error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Also, I don't want to create a new list by removing all None values and then enumerating over it as that way it will alter the indices of rest of the elements and i will not get the desired output.

So lets say here is my list:

```
l = [None, 5, 0, 7, 2, 11]
```

and i want `indices of all elements between 0 & 5`
So my output should look like:

```
output = [1, 2, 4]
```

The exact syntax which I am using as of now which is giving me the above mentioned error is:

```
result = np.array([[i, v] for i, v  in enumerate(l) if v >= 0 and v <= 5])
```

Also, I want to keep on using the above way of doing things in my code as there is more to do with it. Just hoping to tweak the above syntax only to achieve what I need to do... Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy - just add a check for `None` in your condition:

```
result = np.array([[i, v] for i, v  in enumerate(l) if v is not None and v >= 0 and v <= 5])
```

Also, while you're there, you can condense the check you are making to just `0 <= v <= 5`:

```
result = np.array([[i, v] for i, v  in enumerate(l) if v is not None and 0 <= v <= 5])
```

Finally, since you're using `numpy`, you can improve this further if you use masked arrays to handle the logic of your `None`s, and then you can apply the value checking directly with the numpy array which will work a lot faster. I'll leave you to figure out how to make use of masked arrays since that's not your question here.

Comment: @Ixop How silly of me  to have not thought about it? It was indeed a very straightforward solution. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition to check if `v` is `None`. You should also modify the results, `[i, v]` will return a list of the index and value, so `result` will be list of lists `[[1 5] [2 0] [4 2]]`

```
result = np.array([i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v is not None and 0 <= v <= 5])
# output [1 2 4]
```

Comment: @lenik the op asked fro results `[1, 2, 4]`. `[i, v]` won't produce it.