# Round list values with list comprehension including None

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nonetype, floor

I want to round down values of a list ignoring None.

Given a list without None values I would do it like:

```
import math        
value_list = [1.5, 2.3, 3.2, 4.7]
rounded_list = [math.floor(elem) for elem in value_list]
```

A list including None values gives an error:

```
import math        
value_list = [1.5, 2.3, None, 4.7]
rounded_list = [math.floor(elem) for elem in value_list]
```

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

I have this solution but I'm wondering, if there is a one-liner for it

```
import math 
value_list = [1.5, 2.3, None, 4.7]

for i in range(len(value_list)):
    try:
        value_list[i] = math.floor(value_list[i])
    except:
        pass
```

Furthermore [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850467/is-there-any-way-or-a-specified-parameter-to-use-enumerate-in-python-while-skipp) is skipping the None values and I explicitly want to keep them.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `None` values in the rounded list?

Comment: Do you actually want to `round` or `floor` the numbers, and in case of the latter, do you want to `floor` towards lower or towards zero for negative numbers? Depending on that, you may want to use `round`, `floor`, or `int` respectively.

Comment: Not a very good dupe I would say...

Comment: Without a ternary, you could also use `[x and math.floor(x) for x in value_list]` Not saying that you _should_ use this, but you _could_...

Comment: Thanks at all and sry for late response. Yes, I want to keep the None values. Don't know, why it is marked as duplicate, because the associated question is skipping None values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. Rounded values including None

```
rounded_list = [None if elem is None else math.floor(elem) for elem in value_list]
```

Option 2. Rounded values without None

```
rounded_list = [math.floor(elem) for elem in value_list if not elem is None]
```

Comment: The first will convert `0.0` to `None` (better do `if elem is None` or `else elem`), and the second will remove all `None` (and also `0.0`)

Comment: @tobias_k--thanks for the tip.  Made correction.

Comment: You should do the comparison with `None` using `is`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @yatu--thanks, made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

value_list = [1.5, 2.3, None, 4.7]
rounded_list = [None if x is None else math.floor(x) for x in value_list]
print(rounded_list)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, None, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a check for `None` like this:

```py
import math        
value_list = [1.5, 2.3, None, 4.7]
rounded_list = [math.floor(elem) for elem in value_list if elem is not None]

print(rounded_list)
>>> [1, 2, 4]
```

EDIT 
If you want to keep the `None` values you can do this:

```py
import math        
value_list = [1.5, 2.3, None, 4.7]
rounded_list = [math.floor(elem) if elem is not None else None for elem in value_list]

print(rounded_list)
>>> [1, 2, None, 4]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep the `None`, though...

Comment: @tobias_k oh, ok, thanks.